# how to plot a matrix as scatter plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a binary files that is 1440 columns*720 rows. I read it into R as a matrix in order to plot it as scatter plot, but I wonder why the resulting plot was something weird (I do not have enough rep to upload the plot).

```
conner <- file("D:\\complete.bin","rb")
corrs <- readBin(conner, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
y1 <- t(matrix((data=corrs), ncol=720, nrow=1440))
plot(y1)
```

so I want to convert the matrix to be:

```
(5,4,5,2,1,6,9,8,......................................)all values
```

and plot them as a scatter plot.

So how can we plot a matrix as scatter plot and not as an image?

Comment: a scatter plot takes two vectors x, y, and plots {(x[0], y[0]), (x[1], y[1]), ..., (x[n], y[n])}.  I'm not sure what you mean when you ask for a scatterplot of a 720 x 1440 matrix

Comment: It's not about density, but about the fact that scatter plot uses two vectors for coordinates where to draw points, it's not clear how would you like to use the values in matrix as coordinates.

Comment: Oh you can do that but the y in that case is not a matrix but a vector, and you asked about plotting a matrix... So you could just use `plot(corrs)`.

Comment: readBin returns a vector as "corrs", then you convert that to a matrix in y1.  Have you tried plot(corrs)?

Comment: Please note my edits to your question. We understand that not everyone speaks English natively, but if you're going to continue to ask questions here you are going to have to put some significant effort into making your Q's understandable, otherwise you will continue to attract negative responses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you want to plot all the values in your matrix. You can do it like this:

```
y<-matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)
y
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  1.8185601  0.6745425 0.5584071 -1.0631574 -0.6729403
[2,] -0.5075942  1.8931653 0.9951502 -1.0469745  0.3087902
[3,] -0.8855172 -0.5571970 0.8180533 -1.6210277  1.0537248
[4,]  0.2876082  0.1775348 1.2246795  0.7912057 -1.3986548
[5,] -0.2157624 -0.4067569 1.0355421 -0.7114979 -0.2311551

plot(c(y))
```

But in you case you already have a vector `corrs` so just use `plot(corrs)`.

Comment: Just a short note: the reason plotting the matrix itself didn't work is that R in that case assumes you mean the first column to be the x values and the second column to be y values, and simply ignores the rest.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming corrs is an image of your precomputed scatterplot.

Try

```
image(matrix((data=corrs), ncol=720, nrow=1440))
```

or

```
library(fields)
image.plot(matrix((data=corrs), ncol=720, nrow=1440))
```